# Please explain what's going on with this Geodesic Equation of a Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm using the Christoffel Symbols found on this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985964/christoffel-symbols-for-spherical-polar-coordinates) to generate a set of three coupled differential equations as solutions to the *Geodesic Equation of a Sphere*, I have:
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\lambda^2}-r\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}-r\space Sin(\theta)^2\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}=0$$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}-Cos(\theta)Sin(\theta)\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}=0$$
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}+2\space Cot(\theta)\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}=0$$
So far, so good.  My eventual goal here is to find the geodesic on a sphere that expands with time (that is, a preliminary step to a full FLRW model).  Now I want to program this formula in Mathematica to see what happens on the surface of a sphere.  Here's the code:

```
X[r_, theta_, phi_] := r*Cos[phi]*Sin[theta];
Y[r_, theta_, phi_] := r*Sin[phi]*Sin[theta];
Z[r_, theta_, phi_] := r*Cos[theta];
R[r_, theta_, phi_] := {X[r, theta, phi], Y[r, theta, phi], Z[r, theta, phi]};

equations =
{
  r[0] == 1.,
  theta[0] == 1.,
  phi[0] == 1.,
  Derivative[1][r][0] == 0.,
  Derivative[1][theta][0] == 0.5,
  Derivative[1][phi][0] == 1.,
  Derivative[2][r][lambda] - r[lambda]*D[theta[lambda], lambda]*D[theta[lambda], lambda] - r[lambda]*Sin[theta[lambda]]^2*D[phi[lambda], lambda]*D[phi[lambda], lambda] == 0,
  Derivative[2][theta][lambda] + (2/r[lambda])*D[r[lambda], lambda]*D[theta[lambda], lambda] - Cos[theta[lambda]]*Sin[theta[lambda]]*D[phi[lambda], lambda]*D[phi[lambda], lambda] == 0,
  Derivative[2][phi][lambda] + (2/r[lambda])*D[phi[lambda], lambda]*D[r[lambda], lambda] + 2*Cot[theta[lambda]]*D[phi[lambda], lambda]*D[theta[lambda], lambda] == 0
};
S[lambda_] = {r[lambda], theta[lambda], phi[lambda]} /. First[NDSolve[equations, {r, theta, phi}, {lambda, 0, 5}]];
surface = ParametricPlot3D[{R[1., theta, phi]}, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}];
Show[{surface, ParametricPlot3D[R[S[lambda][[1]], S[lambda][[2]], S[lambda][[3]]], {lambda, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Now, here's where I need some help.  If I plot this, I get:

[image]

Which appears to be a tangent vector.  I was expecting the $r$ value to remain constant around the sphere since I set the initial distance to 1. and the velocity to 0.  If I change the second derivative formula to:

```
  Derivative[2][r][lambda] == 0,
```

Then I get the expected Geodesic:
[image]
Can someone explain to me what is going on?  Did I make a mistake? Or should I not expect the $r$ coordinate to follow the Geodesic because it's normal to the surface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an obvious typo in the derivation of the equations of motion on a sphere. First, we write down the coordinates and the metric tensor for a sphere with a given radius `r0=1` immersed in 4D:

```
n = 4; r0=1;
coord = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
metric ={{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, r0^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};
```

We calculate the Christoffel symbols for this case

```
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]

affine := 
  affine = Simplify[
    Table[(1/2)*
      Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
         s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
          D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
          D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
      1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];


listaffine := 
  Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
     0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i, j, k]], affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i,
     1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}];


TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

And so there are two non-zero components
$$\Gamma[3,4,4]=-\cos\theta \sin\theta, \Gamma[4,4,3]=\cot \theta$$
Now we find the equations of motion
$$\frac {d^2x^i}{ds^2}+\Gamma ^i_{kl}\frac{dx^k}{ds}\frac {dx^l}{ds}=0$$
Put

```
v = {t'[s], r'[s], \[Theta]'[s], \[Phi]'[s]};
```

And then calculate

```
Table[D[v[[i]], s] + ((affine.v).v)[[i]] == 0, {i, n}]
```

Finally, we have a system of equations

```
    eqs = {t''[s] == 0, 
   r''[s] == 
    0, -Cos[\[Theta][s]] Sin[\[Theta][s]] \[Phi]'[s]^2 + \[Theta]''[
      s] == 0, 
   2 Cot[\[Theta][s]] \[Theta]'[s] \[Phi]'[s] + \[Phi]''[s] == 0};

ic = {t[0] == 0, t'[0] == 1, 
   r[0] == 1., \[Theta][0] == 1., \[Phi][0] == 1., 
   r'[0] == 0., \[Theta]'[0] == 0.5, \[Phi]'[0] == 1.};
```

Now we can display the trajectory on the sphere

```
X[r_, theta_, phi_] := r*Cos[phi]*Sin[theta];
Y[r_, theta_, phi_] := r*Sin[phi]*Sin[theta];
Z[r_, theta_, phi_] := r*Cos[theta];
R[r_, theta_, phi_] := {X[r, theta, phi], Y[r, theta, phi], 
   Z[r, theta, phi]};

S1 = NDSolveValue[
   Flatten[{eqs, ic}], {r[s], \[Theta][s], \[Phi][s]}, {s, 0, 5}];
surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{R[1., theta, phi]}, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 
    2*Pi}];
Show[{surface, 
  ParametricPlot3D[R[S1[[1]], S1[[2]], S1[[3]]], {s, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Could you direct me to my typo, please?  Your solution is excellent, but it would be useful to me to see where my original solution broke.

Comment: You used Christoffel symbols for spherical coordinates in 3D, but not for a sphere.

Comment: Your equations describe a straight line in 3D (geodesic in empty space).

Comment: I believe your metric is incorrect.  It should be: `metric = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};`

Comment: You wrote down the metric of empty space in spherical coordinates. I described the metric of a sphere immersed in 4D.

Comment: Alright, this is the concept I think I was missing.  A geodesic on a 2D surface embedded on a 3D sphere would trace a great circle.  But the geodesic in 3D space - without something like gravity to bend it - would be a straight line in both cartesian and polar coordinates.  All I was doing was switching the coordinates to polar in my original post.